# Win 10 Touch Screen Inaccurate in Clone

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

I have a Windows 10 machine with a built-in touch screen. When I connect a second display the system defaults to extend mode then I switch it to clone mode with the touch screen set as primary.

The issue is my touch screen becomes inaccurate. It behaves as if it is set to a different resolution than the display. Middle screen touches are more or less correct and the touch gets further off as you get closer to the edge of the screen.

Drivers:
Intel(R) Graphics Driver: 10.18.10.4252
Touch Screen appears to not have a driver installed, from what I can tell Windows is taking care of it. I did try to install Penmount but saw the same behavior so it was uninstalled.

Touch screen calibration under pen and touch settings does not work as it is not possible to touch the calibration cross hairs at the edge of the screen.

One fix was to put the unit back in extend mode, use setup in tablet settings, select my touch screen, then put it back in clone mode.

I need to better understand what is causing the touch screen to become inaccurate and hopefully find a way to stop this from happening. This will ultimately become a medical device in sort of a kiosk mode. It will be connected to a wide range of external displays that I will know nothing about.

Comment: This is interesting because it sounds almost exactly like the behavior of SCCM Remote Control when the target display has a touch screen and has scaling enabled. So, first question: is there scaling enabled on the display(s)?

Comment: Yes display scaling in the Intel graphics properties is set to "Maintain Display Scaling"

Comment: What about in the Windows Display Settings dialog? It'll likely be the slider labeled "Change the size of text, apps..." and if it isn't all the way to the left, try putting it there, logging off and back on, and see how things work.

Comment: So far the only way I have been able to clear the error is to switch between clone and extend modes with the touch screen as primary, then secondary, then back to primary.  The touch screen will still be inoperable but once the machine is restarted the touch screen magically starts working again.

Comment: The size of text slider was indeed all the way to the left.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think touch-screen tech is where it needs to be yet, frankly. Not on the hardware side, but in the software. I've only tried multiple touch screens on one occasion, and I've never tried clone mode, but I'd imagine it would be exactly the same as running a presentation using a tablet device such as a Surface. I don't have another suggestion at this moment, but I think MS still has a bit of work to do before that system is perfected.